# dynamic query for different values rails 4 activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the query I am trying in my controller

query = []
    if id
          query = "category_id: #{id}"
        end

```
    @posts = Post.where(query)
```

But throwing error as `ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"`

Why this is not working any other way to do it

```
if id
    query << {sub_category_id: id}
end

if test
    query << {test_id: test}
end
    @posts = Post.where(query)
```

Is there any way of doing like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this:

```
@posts = Post.scoped
@posts = @posts.where(category_id: id) if id
```

(in case you're playing codegolf)

**Edit:** *(this is definitely a side note that isn't at all relevant)*

Your original solution relies on one of my least favorite features of Ruby. Consider the following code:

```
if false
    a = 4
end
puts a
```

I would expect the `puts a` to fail with a NameError (undefined local variable "a"), but no! The Ruby parser hits `a =` and then initalizes its value to `nil`. So, despite the fact that there is *no way* for the innards of that `if` statement to run, it still impacts the other code.

Answer (score 1):

Change `query` to a hash instead of string:

```
if id
  query = { category_id: id }
end

@posts = Post.where(query)
```

The reason `query = "category_id: #{id}"` did not work is because the supplied string is literally used in the query generated by ActiveRecord, i.e. your select query will have `category_id: 1` (assuming id is 1) in the where clause.  And this is not a valid SQL syntax.

Please read on how you can use strings in conditions following [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions).  Thanks to  @RustyToms for suggesting the link.

**Update:** ( Add extra conditions to the `query` hash )

```
if id
  query[:sub_category_id] = id
end

if test
  query[:test_id] = test
end

@posts = Post.where(query)
```

Comment: Beautiful. You can also do it as a string, read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions

Comment: @RustyToms, yes I was updating the post with how the symbol `category_id:` is treated as column name.  And thank you for the link.

Comment: Ya thats working good. If when I try this throwing syntax error `query =''` query += {sub_category_id: id}

Comment: @vee now getting error as `no implicit conversion of Hash into String`

Comment: @vee ya tried the updated one getting error as `undefined local variable or method `query' for`